# Python's @property equivalent in class declaration in Processing?

Tags: java, python, class, processing, processing.js

While home on winter break I'm going to try my hand at making some cool stuff using the Processing programming language (of the Java flavor). For my first project, I'd like to define a custom Line class to make doing math on lines easier. In python, it would be something like this:

```
import numpy as np

class Line():
    def __init__(self, x1, y1, x2, y2):
        self.x1, self.x2 = x1, x2
        self.y1, self.y2 = y1, y2

    @property
    def p1(self):
        return np.array([self.x1, self.y1])

    @property
    def p2(self):
        return np.array([self.x2, self.y2])
```

that way, if x1, ..., y2 are changed, so are the corresponding point vectors. Obviously this example is a bit inefficient, but the point remains. In javascript, I know of the `Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, descriptor)`, but it's not clear

- how to do this in processing
- where this comes into play. What is the equivalent operation when you're defining a class?

Edit: Clarification on why `@property` is specifically useful:

Say that I wish to represent the line two ways, both of which will be stored by the Line object:

- one, the vanilla version: two points, p1 and p2, each consisting of an x, y coordinate.
- two the parameterized version with two points u and v, such that p1 = u and p2 = u + v, with any point on the line segment being given by u + t * v in which t is a scalar between 0 and 1.

If p2 is changed, that will change v, and vice versa. Change p1 will change both u and v. Some of the math is easier to do in terms of the parameterized version and some is easier to do in terms of the vanilla version, so I'd like for any changes done on any attribute to correctly update the other attributes, such that p1, p2 and u, v always represent the same lines.

In python, I could modify the setter and getter methods of the property to appropriately account for all this, but I can't seem to determine a way to do this in Processing.

Comment: Which flavour of Processing are you intending to use ? (Java/JavaScript/Python/etc?)?

Comment: Java (which I think is the original?). Initially I was just going to do Python, but I'm stick of always looking for the python version of x to accomplish task y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this pretty much automatically if you just use regular Processing objects and syntax.

For example, you might use two `PVector` instances to define your endpoints.

```
class Line{
   PVector p1;
   PVector p2;

   public Line(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2){
      p1 = new PVector(x1, y1);
      p2 = new PVector(x2, y2);
   }
}
```

And then if you want to change one of those endpoints, you could simply access the `PVector` instances directly:

```
Line myLine = new Line(0, 10, 25, 100);
println(myLine.p1.x + ", " myLine.p1.y);
myLine.p1.x = 750;
println(myLine.p1.x + ", " myLine.p1.y);
```

You also get all the math stuff already defined in the [PVector class](https://www.processing.org/reference/PVector.html).

You could better "protect" your `PVector` variables by making them final or only allowing users of your `Line` class to change the endpoints through setters that then access the `PVector` instances.

**Edit**: I'll try to answer your additional questions here.

> is public necessary?

It depends on exactly how you're using this class, how you want other people to be able to access it, etc. You can learn about this in [the Processing reference](https://processing.org/reference/public.html), or just google something like "java access modifiers". Or you can just try taking it out and see what happens.

> what if I want both the vanilla definition of a line (x1, y1, x2, y2) and the parameterized (u1, u2, v1, v2, s.t. x1 = u1 and x2 = u1 + v1, etc) versions simultaneously? In this case, and importantly, if x2 is updated, so should v1 be updated.

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking here. When you write your class, you can decide **how you represent your state** and **how you let people interact with that state**.

For example, my example above uses two `PVector` instances to represent the line, and it lets people interact with them directly to modify that line. But I could add a function that lets them define a line as a single point, an angle, and a distance. I just have to make sure I calculate the second point so I can store my state. Something like this:

```
class Line{
   PVector p1;
   PVector p2;

   public Line(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2){
      p1 = new PVector(x1, y1);
      p2 = new PVector(x2, y2);
   }

   public Line(PVector origin, float angle, float distance){
      p1 = origin;
      p2 = new PVector(origin.x + cos(angle)*distance, origin.y + sin(angle)*distance);
   }
}
```

Notice that second constructor allows the user to specify a line in a completely different way, but I'm still storing my state as two `PVector` instances. You could store the `angle` and `distance` values if you need them later, and you could have setters that allow the user to modify them- you just have to update your `PVector` values accordingly.

Comment: Great thanks! A few questions though: is `public` necessary? Some of the examples I'm seeing don't use it. Further, what if I want both the vanilla definition of a line (x1, y1, x2, y2) and the parameterized (u1, u2, v1, v2, s.t. x1 = u1 and x2 = u1 + v1, etc) versions simultaneously? In this case, and importantly, if x2 is updated, so should v1 be updated.